# Find out transport type for socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix

I am currently struggling with finding out the ip, port and transport type of a inet/inet6 socket in C.

The problem is that I got a socket fd like

```
int s = socket( ... );
bind(s, soa, soa_len);
```

Now, I got `s` and want to find out which Transport/Interface/Port it is bound to.
Interface and Port is easy enough via

```
struct sockaddr_storage sa = {};:w
getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr*) &sa, sizeof(sa));
/* parse the fields of sa depending on sa.sa_family */
```

However, I cannot figure out a way to find out whether `s` is a TCP or UDP socket - it must be somehow associated however - So:

How can I find out the transport protocol `s` uses?

Comment: `struct sockaddr_storage sa = {};:w` is not valid C. That looks more like C++/vim.

Comment: @melpomene You gotta make sure your post is saved to the web. :D :w

Comment: It is valid C11 I am quite sure. For the ':w' - too much vim tonight you are right ;)

Comment: @MichaelBeer, although I am prepared to believe that your C compiler accepts an empty pair of braces as an initializer, that *does not* conform to C11 or any earlier C standard.  An initializer list must contain at least one initializer.  The canonical way to write an initializer such as you seem to be trying to express is `{0}`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will leave the typo there, otherwise these comments become ununderstandable, and I think people will get the basic point of my question nevertheless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getsockopt(descriptor, SO_TYPE, ...)` as described in the [`man 7 socket`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) man page. For example:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

int socket_type(const int fd)
{
    int        type = -1;
    socklen_t  typelen = sizeof type;

    if (fd == -1) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &type, &typelen) == -1)
        return -1;

    errno = 0;
    return type;
}
```

For TCP (`AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` socket families), this will return `SOCK_STREAM`; for UDP, `SOCK_DGRAM`.

Comment: Hey, that has been precisely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot - you saved my night ;)